# Flyway migrations using remote files?

Tags: flyway

Is it possible to use Flyway locations that point to a remote server? For example, can I have Flyway installed on a DB server but the migration files on an application server.

I've looked through the Flyway docs, but haven't found an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No directly, but you could mount the remote directory via NFS and that should work.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks for the quick response!